# Extract RGB and RGBA from css Rules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some string like below :

```
"linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,0,0,0.4) 0,rgba(0,230,175,0.4) 100%);"
```

i want to extract all rgba and rgb from this stirng like `rgba(255,0,0,0.4)` and `rgba(0,230,175,0.4)` . it try to search and find some question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751877/how-to-extract-r-g-b-a-values-from-css-color) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543818/regex-javascript-to-match-both-rgb-and-rgba) but that answer doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to extract all `rgba` and `rgb` from the stirng

I hope you don't want to validate the digits in rgba and rgb, if yes then get the matched group from index 1 using capturing groups.

```
(rgba?\((?:\d{1,3}[,\)]){3}(?:\d+\.\d+\))?)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/3)

---

You can get the values using `Lazy` way as well in the same way from matched group index 1.

```
(rgba?.*?\))
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/4)

Last Pattern explanation:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    rgb                      'rgb'
    a?                       'a' (optional)
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times)
    \)                       ')'
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to match the strings, for instance `rgba(255,0,0,0.4)`, without parsing the values, just use:

```
arrayOfMatches = yourString.match(/rgba\([^)]+\)/g);
```